# Prevent Indexing of 404 Page

Tags: php, noindex

I'm tryying to prevent search engines from indexing my 404 page which is in a template called 404.php.  I do not create an actual page, I simply rely on the php template for my 404 errors.

I'm using the code below and it's not working, I'm unsure what the best way to go about this is and I would appreciate help.

```
<?php if(is_single('404.php')): ?>
<META NAME="ROBOTS" CONTENT="NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW" />
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This won't ever return true:

```
if ( is_single( '404.php' ) ) {}
```

The [`is_single()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_single) conditional only returns true in a *single blog post* context. The parameter it accepts is a post ID, slug, or title.

The `404.php` file is a *template file*, not a *post*. Use [`is_404()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_404) instead:

```
if ( is_404() ) {}
```

Answer (score 0):

Isn't this fixed by creating a robot.txt at the root of your ftp like so:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /404.php
```

Comment: Search engines, like Google, do not follow robots.txt